# How do you add items to an array list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

So here is my array list declaration:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<WordItem>>list = new ArrayList<LinkedList<WordItem>>(26);
```

When I do, for example:

```
list.add(a)
```

it gives me an error of:

```
CountWords.java:17: error: no suitable method found for add(int)
            list.add(addr(ch));
```

Comment: Why are you adding an integer to a list of lists of word items?

Comment: word items is a type of the arraylist. How else would you add the letter 'a' to the list?

Comment: Your ArrayList "list" is a list of LinkedLists. You can't add an int to it, only another LinkedList.

Comment: you are not adding the letter 'a' you are adding the variable `a` which looks to be an int from the error message.  And since the error message is looking for a `char` not a `LinkedList<WordItem>` I think you are showing incorrectly pasted code.

Comment: so, what's the correct way of adding the letter 'a' to the list?

Comment: @KyleButler Please define _"the list"_ because that is a little ambiguous right now.  And show your `WordItem` class

Comment: Make sure the variable you're inserting matches the variable your Array is declared to handle and that the method `add` is for the same variable type as well.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 that's not a proper answer because it changes the whole design.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable a must be of the type `LinkedList<WordItem>` in order to add it to your variable named list.

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates an ArrayList of Strings and adds the letter "a" to it.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
```

Here is the documentation please read more on using ArrayList's
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html